# How to completely hide the EditText that is used to change input type to numeric SIP

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, sip, numeric

I am having a problem with EditText control and not sure how to make it completely hidden. My requirement is to show Numeric SIP from a webview control using InputMethodManager and showSoftInput always defaults to alpha numeric keyboard. So I have created a hidden EditText control and changed the input type from that control and it worked fine but the problem is that the hidden control can still be accessible and it is always displayed at top/left corner. Is there a way to move/align the hidden EdiTtext exactly with the control that I am editing and to hide that completely.

```
InputMethodManager imm;
if (mWebEditText == null)
{
    mWebEditText = new WebEditText(Common.mainActivity.getApplicationContext(),view.getView());
}

mWebEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
mWebEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

AbsoluteLayout webEditTextPanel = (AbsoluteLayout) Common.mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.editext_panel);
webEditTextPanel.removeAllViews();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(area.width(), area.height());
lp.leftMargin = area.left;
lp.topMargin = area.top;
webEditTextPanel.addView(mWebEditText, lp);

mWebEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
mWebEditText.setCursorVisible(false); 
mWebEditText.setBackgroundColor(0x00FFFFFF); // If I do this the bounding rectangle is hidden but if we tap on top/left corner then we can see the edit box
mWebEditText.requestFocus();
imm.showSoftInput(mWebEditText, 0);
```

EditText definition:

```
<AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/editext_panel" android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="false"    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:visibility="visible">
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Bounding rectangle at top/left corner]

Comment: have  u tried setting background color as transparent?

Comment: @AND_DEV, please see my comments in the code   mWebEditText.setBackgroundColor(0x00FFFFFF); // If I do this the bounding rectangle is hidden but if we tap on top/left corner then we can see the edit box

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide use `editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` if you want that it is completely gone and no space is allotted to it in UI then use the command `editText.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: If I use either INVISIBLE or GONE options then I dont get the SIP when I tap on the control. I get the SIP only when the visibility is set to VISIBLE

Answer (score 0):

Moving the control off the screen worked fine. i.e. the control was hidden and the number SIP popped up fine.

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(area.width(), area.height(), -200, -200);
```